# Installing Ubuntu on new SSD from within Ubuntu running off HDD on same PC

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

Have Ubuntu with lot of software with some some non-trivial / non-default configuration (especially done for tweaking system for low-latency audio production), all of which would take quite some time to re-trace and re-perform, if done from scratch. Those are actions performed after OS installation from downloaded ISO image.

Given that I already have a fully functional Ubuntu setup, currently installed on the PC's HDD (2TB SATA @7200rpm, installed on "default" partition/volume configuration), I was wondering if there is a way to install Ubuntu on the new SSD, where-by the initial OS installation is done using a downloaded Ubuntu ISO image, but all other additional software is taken from the cache of software installer packages (apt cache) of the running OS instance ? What can I do for the configuration ?

Actually, I don't mind having a sort of dual-boot for a while. The intent is to use SSD for OS/applications and short-term working data (like audio, video files). The HDD will keep all my long-term, large data files.

Comment: If this is the same OS release you want to put on the SDD as the HDD, clonezilla would avoid having to reinstall/reconfigure all your manually installed packages. A different OS release would probably not be able to use your currently downloaded packages.

Comment: Thanks @ubfan1. It is indeed the same version of Ubuntu. Will read up about Clonezilla. I suppose it does bit-for-bit cloning of HDD to SSD. If a, any chance it might setup the OS our SSD filesystem in a suboptimal way? Something that prevents the PC from maximizing the performance gain of SSD?

Comment: Clnezilla requirement **The destination partition must be equal or larger than the source one. ** makes it a non-candidate solution, in my case.